# No events are firing when a `<select>` is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to find a way to listen for a `select` being closed. Surprisingly, no events are being fired when the `select` is open. Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/smka7ngh/1/

Is this normal browser behavior? I'm on Chrome/OSX.

If this is consistent across browsers, then I can do something like this to check when it's closed:

```
$('select').on('click', function(){ // opened
  $('select').one(allEvents, function(){
    $('select').trigger('closed');
  });
});
```

I'm guessing there's no other way to listen for the `select` being closed, or is there?

Comment: You can listen for a change.https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: you can listen for the `change` event and that will tell you when a new option is selected.

Comment: try change event binding

Comment: change is not fired when a select is opened and just closed again. I think your idea would cover it. I first thought blur but that wouldn't fire in a open close open situation.

Comment: @BG101 is right, `change` fires only when the value changes.